# Jenkins - Simple build does not complete in windows. Runs forever

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jenkins, msbuild

I am exploring jenkins. I am trying to build an ASP.Net MVC project with jenkins. I have a build step to compile and build the project.

Following is the console output. I understand why the build failed. But the problem is, jenkins build does not stop for ever.

[image]

Any thoughts ? Thanks.

Comment: Did you check `<yourserver>/log/all` for some odd exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was due to MS Build's default configuration. When I made the build to be in release mode, the build got completed as expected. I am not sure why it did't work in the default mode though.

```
/t:Build /p:Configuration=Release
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to complete build when it stucked, you can try [Build-timeout Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build-timeout+Plugin)

> Build Environment-->Abort the build if it's stuck-->Timeout minutes

[image]